# Opencart Custom URL Rewrite htacces

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, opencart

I am using Opencart 1.5.6.4 and I want to rewrite an Opencart URL, basic URLs are like:

```
/index.php?route=product/product&path=25_28&product_id=33
```

If I insert a custom name in my admin panel of Opencart for example `Product` I'll get:

```
/product
```

This works fine but I made a custom page and this simply adds `&promo=1` to the link.

So how I get to my custom page I use:

```
/index.php?route=product/product&path=25_28&product_id=33&custom=1
```

What I want to is that the link above + `&custom=1` can be accessed by using the SEO friendly URL:

```
/product/promo
```

In this case `/promo` has to be the `&custom=1`, I don't know how to do this.

For the people with no Opencart knowledge maybe the links below will help (I'm not that good with PHP)

- https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php
- https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/library/url.php

And here is my .htacces file:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]    
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]    
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)    
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: [OpenCart - Extensions](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension&filter_search=friendly%20urls)

Comment: Hi Prix, It really needs to be custom i can not use a extension for this.

Answer (score 0):

Without extension you cannot change urls and customize it